# Finding minimum graph of $k$ disjoints component

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Sorry for the english, I tried to make it the most clear possible.

Be $G$ a connected graph not directed, I have to find an algorithm that given $n$ the quantity of vertex and $0<k<n$ disjoint components gives a graph such the weight of it's maximum edge is the minimum possible. Then, proof that this algorithm is correct.

So the algorithm I came up with is:

First whit some known algorithm, generate the minimum spanning tree. (for example whith the prim [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm))

For 1 to k get the maximum edge of this Minimum spanning tree and delete it.

done.

Proof that this work:

By induction:

Base Step($k=1$) :

Let $G$ be our graph of $n$ vertex and connected, getting a minimum spanning tree of $G$, we know we have a subgraph such all the vertex are connected there are no circuits and the sum of the weights of the edges is minimum.

If the sum of the weights of the edges is minimum, then this means the maximum weight of an edge is minimum. Then this step holds.

Inductive step(if $i-1 \rightarrow i$):

Let $G'$ be the minimum spanning tree. By Inductive hypothesis I know i can get the firsts $i-1$ edges and I get the disjoint graph the maximum weight of an edge is minimum for $i-1$ connected components. Then deleting the maximum weight edge, I get the disjoint graph the maximum weight of an edge is minimum for $i$ connected components.

I'm not very convinced this proof is correct, the inductive step feels very rare, and I think I used it wrong.

What do you think?

Comment: It seems that $G$ is a directed graph (you use "strongly connected"), but the answer doesn't seem to depend on it. Is that intentional (i.e. I'm asking about problem formulation, not your solution)?

Comment: no, it's not directed. I wanted to express that every vertex is connected with each other.

Comment: Then just say that it is connected. Terms strongly/weakly connected are for directed graphs. (You can also add that the graph is undirected, it helps.)

Comment: I know you did your best with the English, but I still really don't understand what the algorithm is trying to accomplish. Can you try to explain differently?

Comment: Given a graph such every node is connected with a given weight, find the set of edges shuch that the biggest weight is the minimum possible. The set has to have at least $n-k$ edges.

Comment: Questions: (1) The edges have weights, right? You said nodes have a given weight. (2) You say "every node is connected". Do you mean every two nodes are connected by an edge, i.e., $G$ is a complete graph? (3) You say "The set has to have at least $n-k$ edges." In the question you said something about $k$ disjoint components. Do you want your output graph to have exactly (or at least) $k$ disjoint components? It may be helpful to add to your post the  problem as stated in your own language.

Comment: (1) yes
(2) yes
(3) I think is the same, given the conditions. So I stated it differently but I think there are equivalent

Comment: Hint 1: Your proof might be a bit oversimplified -- it states the true-but-non-entirely obvious part without actually proving it.

Hint 2: It's possible to simplify the algorithm you proposed and, at the same time, make the proof easier too -- take Kruskal's algorithm for the minimum spanning tree and consider what happens if you terminate it prematurely.